# I've got this method to get the data mobile used for every installed app

Tags: java, android

Hello this is my method to get the used mobile data for every installed application in an android phone but it only get me the data used by my app not all the apps

I need it to get the data mobile used by every app installed in the phone

```java
void OthernetworkUsage() {

        List<PackageInfo> packs = getPackageManager().getInstalledPackages(PackageManager.GET_PERMISSIONS);
        for(PackageInfo p : packs){
            //  if(!isSystemPackage(p)){
            if(usesInternet(p)) {
                long received = TrafficStats.getUidRxBytes(p.applicationInfo.uid);

                long sent = TrafficStats.getUidTxBytes(p.applicationInfo.uid);
                String appName = p.applicationInfo.loadLabel(getPackageManager()).toString();
                int uid = p.applicationInfo.uid;
                Toast.makeText(this, "uid: "+uid+"/Kb - name: "+appName+": Sent = "+sent/1024+"Kb, Rcvd = "+received/1024+"Kb", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
            //}
        }
    }
```

I really need help in that case.

Comment: I'm not sure that you can.  That seems like the type of thing that used to be allowed but Android has now hidden for privacy concerns.

Comment: @GabeSechan you are right. From [doc](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/TrafficStats.html#getUidRxBytes(int))  : _Starting in Build.VERSION_CODES.N this will only report traffic statistics for the calling UID. It will return UNSUPPORTED for all other UIDs for privacy reasons. To access historical network statistics belonging to other UIDs, use NetworkStatsManager._

Comment: @Kilarn123 can you please show me a tuto on how to use NetworkStatsManager and maybe what to replace in my method, thank you.

Comment: @hollygreads i never worked with that, i just took a look at the doc but [here is the doc for NetworkStatsManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/usage/NetworkStatsManager.html). Hope this help

Comment: thank you i ll take a look at it.